# Date parsing a string type date and querying the rails activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a model(Rails and Mongoid) in which one `field` called `ref_year` stores the date in string format.

I am trying to pass an array of 5 dates to the model and query it based on the descending order.

If I do:

```
Model.in(ref_year: ['2017-03-31','2018-03-31','2019-03-31','2020-03-31','2021-03-31']).order_by(ref_year: :desc).limit(3)
```

I am getting the desired result. But `order_by` on string is not reliable solution.

How can I Date parse the array of DATE strings that I am passing and get the last 3 records?

Comment: Why do you say that sorting on strings is not reliable?